# Get an array back from an itertools.chain object

Tags: python, python-itertools

Suppose I have `list_of_numbers = [[1, 2], [3], []]` and I want the much simpler object list object `x = [1, 2, 3]`.

Following the logic of [this related solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406199/2232265), I do

```
list_of_numbers = [[1, 2], [3], []]
import itertools
chain = itertools.chain(*list_of_numbers)
```

Unfortunately, `chain` is not exactly what I want because (for instance) running `chain` at the console returns `<itertools.chain object at 0x7fb535e17790>`.

What is the function `f` such that if I do `x = f(chain)` and then type `x` at the console I get `[1, 2, 3]`?

**Update:**  Actually the result I ultimately need is `array([1, 2, 3])`.  I'm adding a line in a comment on the selected answer to address this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`list`. If you do `list(chain)` it should work. But use this just for debugging purposes, it could be inefficient in general.

Comment: How is this inefficient?

Comment: Having imported numpy as np, the one-line version that I'm using now is this:  `x = np.array(list(itertools.chain(*list_of_numbers))`.

Answer (score 3):

If your ultimate goal is to get a Numpy array then you should use [`numpy.fromiter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html) here:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list_of_numbers = [[1, 2], [3], []]
>>> np.fromiter(chain(*list_of_numbers), dtype=int)
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> list_of_numbers = [[1, 2]*1000, [3]*1000, []]*1000
>>> %timeit np.fromiter(chain(*list_of_numbers), dtype=int)
10 loops, best of 3: 103 ms per loop
>>> %timeit np.array(list(chain(*list_of_numbers)))
1 loops, best of 3: 199 ms per loop
```

Comment: looks promising, although I can't seem to get the `%timeit` parts to work.  Some kind of syntax error.  I tried importing `timeit` first, and that did not help.  In general I don't follow your speed comparison. Are you saying that `numpy.fromiter` is the faster option?  If so, is that the main reason for preferring it?

Comment: `%timeit` is part of [IPython shell](http://ipython.org/). Of course speed is one reason to prefer `.fromiter`, plus we don't have to create an intermediate list here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `list(chain)`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: it doesn't answer the question 'What is the function f such that if I do x = f(chain) and then type x at the console I get [1, 2, 3]?' or the title statement 'Get a “plain old” array back from an itertools.chain object'